# html and css tags not working correctly possibly descender tags?

Tags: html, css, tags

So I'm creating a website for a class and I for the life of me can not figure out why my `<p>` tag is not correctly working when I try to modify it in the css. If anyone could help that would be amazing.

Html:

```html
<body>
<section>
<section id="pictures">
    <div>
        <img src="images/ritual4.jpg" id="slide" class="floatLeft" alt="This is a picture of a group of young men posing and smiling">
        <script language="JavaScript">slideIt();</script>
        <p>Ritual and Mills Music Mission</p>
        <img src="images/ossian.jpg" alt="This is a picture of a group of dressed up men posing with an older gentleman.">
        <p>Spaghetti Dinner Fall 2015</p>
    </div>
</section>
    <section id="main">
    <h1>About Phi Mu Alpha</h1>
<hr>
<div>
<p id="text">Phi Mu Alpha Sinfonia:</p>
<p id="text1">Phi Mu Alpha Sinfonia was established on October 6th, 1898</p>

    <p id="text">
    Gamma Beta Chapter:
    </p>
    </section>
</section>
</div>
</body>
```

Css:

```css
#main h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 28px;
}
hr{
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
#main #text{
    text-indent: 5%;
    font-family: courier new, Georgia, Times;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#main #text1{
    text-indent: 5%;
    font-family: courier new, Georgia, Times;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

body #main p{
    text-indent: 8%;
    font-family: courier new, Georgia, Times;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To be honest your code is a mess. I changed some but if you want to make it neater I can change your code, but if not then just look at the following code:

HTML:

```
<section id="pictures">
    <div>
        <img src="images/ritual4.jpg" id="slide" class="floatLeft" alt="This is a picture of a group of young men posing and smiling">
        <script language="JavaScript">slideIt();</script>
        <p>Ritual and Mills Music Mission</p>
        <img src="images/ossian.jpg" alt="This is a picture of a group of dressed up men posing with an older gentleman.">
        <p>Spaghetti Dinner Fall 2015</p>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="main">
    <h1>About Phi Mu Alpha</h1>
    <hr>
    <div>
      <p id="text">Phi Mu Alpha Sinfonia:</p>
      <p id="text1">Phi Mu Alpha Sinfonia was established on October 6th, 1898</p>

      <p id="text">
        Gamma Beta Chapter:
      </p>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
hr {
    color:#fff;
}

#main h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
}

#main p {
    text-indent: 8%;
    font-family: "Courier New", Georgia, Times;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#main #text {
    text-indent: 5%;
    font-size: 20px;
}
#main #text1 {
    text-indent: 5%;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```